# How can I resume a thread which is waiting for a resource?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I interrupt/resume a resource waiting thread back to other works? Say, My thread is waiting for response from a resource where the resource hanged or not in the state of response. How can I resume back that thread to do other works?

Can other thread send a exception to the waiting thread, so that with an exception, it can come back to it's other work?

UPDATE :

I have tried it in the following way, but no use.

I have timeout Thread, which will check whether default timeout has occurred to that particular Transaction on which the first thread wait, and if so, fire interrupt() call on the first thread.

Comment: for a interrupt to work, whatever the tread is waiting on has to be *interruptible*. Normally I would redesign this to have a queue of tasks to be executed by (say an `ExecutorService`) and this guy can somehow check whether a particular task is ready to execute (for example all expected io has completed.) This does mean converting your system to an asynchronous system - which is a non-trivial task.

Comment: if you are waiting for a resource, you should use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long)

Comment: What kind of operation the thread blocks on?

Comment: Wait on whatever monitor is signaled by the resource with a timeout.

Comment: @EyalSchneider: The Thread waits for response from long running hive query, some time, these hadoop hang so the application can't get the response on time, so it's waiting and application also hangs. Hive JDBC doesn't support most of the Connection method to close or cancel the request!

Comment: If you are blocking on a non-interruptible IO operation, a thread interruption won't work. You probably need a timeout control thread, that closes the connection when the timeout is reached. The thread waiting on the connection will immediately fail, with an exception. You should check whether your connectivity API allows closing the underlying connection.

Comment: @EyalSchneider: I've tried the same way with hashed wheel timer mechanism to close the connection, but, the Hive JDBC api still not support it yet.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on many factors. 
The "right" way to interrupt a thread is to use the thread.interrupt() method. This requires the thread's code to be cooperative; it should be aware of the interruption, either by handling the InterruptedException thrown by interruptible operations (such as wait or sleep), or by checking the interrupted flag of the current thread regularly.

Then, the code should decide what consequences the interruption should have. Usually, you would like a thread to terminate gracefully in case of interruption.

Instead of using interruption, I would check whether your blocking operation has a built in timeout mechanism. If it's blocked on obj.wait() for example, then you could use obj.wait(timeout) instead.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) the thread. using the Thread.interrupt mechanism, google it.